# Open MPI 4.0 core and memory binding

Tags: mpi, numa

I need some hints on how to achieve the core and memory bindings I have in mind, using Open MPI 4.0.1.
This is for a single compute node with 8 NUMA nodes and 64 cores, namely 2x AMD Epyc 7551, SMT disabled.

The cores on this system are numbered according to the following scheme:

[image]

Now I have 3 different binding policies in mind, let's call them "close", "spread" and "scatter". I'll give 3 examples for each one with 6,16 and 48 threads to make my idea clear (hopefully). But I need methods that work with arbitrary numbers of MPI threads between 1 and 64.

**1: "close"** The idea here is to keep the threads as close as possible, i.e. minimising core-core latency.
[image][image][image]

**2: "spread"** With the idea to make use of all available memory bandwidth

[image][image][image]

**3: "scatter"** The idea behind this is that each NUMA node is divided again into 2 groups of 4 cores, where each group has its own L3 cache. Compared to "spread", this policy should maximise the amount of L3 cache available to each thread.

[image][image][image]

Which arguments do I need to pass to mpirun in order to achieve each of these 3 policies? Or any other method if this can not be achieved without the help of e.g. machinefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the hardware to test it, so I cannot guarantee this is a correct answer

- "close"
  `mpirun --bind-to core --rank-by core --map-by core ...`
- "spread"
  `mpirun --bind-to core --rank-by core --map-by numa ...`
- "scatter"
  `mpirun --bind-to core --rank-by core --map-by l3cache ...`

you can also `mpirun --report-bindings ...` in order to see how the MPI tasks were pinned by Open MPI.

Comment: That does not quite do the trick, at least for spread and scatter. Each rank is still assigned a range of cores, not a single one. And map-by l3cache seems to be unaware of the segmentation of L3 cache within each chiplet, assigning one rank to a whole group of 8 cores. Isn't there a different method with offsets that allows us full control, without relying on OpenMPI to guess the architecture correctly?

Comment: You also need `--bind-to core` in all cases.

Comment: I used that too. Still, the bindings for each rank were reported as a range of cores rather than a single core

Comment: if `--bind-to core` reports more than one core (**not** hyper thread) per MPI ranks, this is definitely something you should report to either the Open MPI mailing list or https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues. Note that might be related to `hwloc` or even your Linux kernel.

Comment: My bad, I missed the whole point of your last edit, and confused bind with rank. Thanks a lot